# Meaning of sentence with non-obvious translation

Tags: meaning-in-context

From EasyReaders version of "Der Gasmann":

> Es ist eine schöne Frau, wie sie ein Gericht nicht jeden Tag zu sehen bekommt.

This sentences refers to the moment when a woman turns up at the trial against the main character in the book, and helps solve the mystery.

I kind of guessed that the woman doesn't get to see trials every day, but the word by word translation into English doesn't make much sense. Why  "schöne, wie sie"?

Comment: _"I kind of guessed that the woman doesn't get to see trials every day, but the word by word "_ No. It means the _"Gericht"_ (court) is the one which doesn't meet (such extraordinary) beautiful women every day.

Answer (score 5):

> Es ist eine schöne Frau, wie sie ein Gericht nicht jeden Tag zu sehen bekommt.

The **Gericht** is the assembly of judges (and jury, if that applies), and in a wider sense also attorneys and the public inside the courtroom.

So, it's the judges which aren't used to such beautiful women.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPF3so0Kmfc