# Written on a book I bought "Fresst meinen Sternenstaub, ihr Langweiler!"

Tags: book

What does "Fresst meinen Sternenstaub, ihr Langweiler!" mean? I tried google translate but nothing showed up.

Comment: "Eat my stardust, you bores!" lt. https://www.deepl.com/translator - ein ganz passabler, wenn auch nicht fehlerloser Übersetzungsdienst für kleinere Texte (wenige Absätze). Siehe auch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a24wVSVLtLQ ("We are stardust", Joni Mitchell, @Woodstock)

Comment: Bei der Nachbarfrage hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41769/266 scheitert deepL allerdings schon, selbst wenn man mit "Strafgericht" den dicksten Bock (Gericht i.S.v. Nudelgericht) aus dem Weg räumt.

Comment: I vote to reopen, because this can’t be answered by simply working with a dictionary - even if the OP used something a lot better than google translate.

Comment: I also tend to reopen, however the question lacks of references and context. Please add more information to the question.

Comment: The only thing I would add is the fressen is the "animal" version of essen which is also used in less formal contexts.

Answer (score 7):

**tl/dr**
The other answers in this thread are quite correct, but with all the other items on the web in mind the best answer would be **"Eat my stardust, suckers!"**

And here is why:

Unicorns became cool again with the help of the "Dispicable Me"-movie in 2010. [Especially because of this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8EFVDq0crs). Soon there were memes, clothings, chocolate and toys all over the internet.

With this in mind designers and marketing crews considered what to do next to sell their stuff. Unicorns are magical creatures and when you make them cute and fluffy like in the movies and no noble creatures like in classical fantasy books they become colorful and sparkle. And what else sparkles? Oh yes, stardust, which fits unicorns perfectly.

From there on its just a step from the english mockery [eat my dust](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eat_my_dust) to "eat my stardust". And then someone added "suckers" because it fits the sentence quite well. You can find this sentence on a lot of items [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=eat+my+stardust&source=lnms&tbm=isch).

And then someone in Germany saw this and wanted to sell these items too. He (or she) translated it to "Fresst meinen Sternenstaub, ihr Langweiler!”. Sucker doesn't fit well to Langweiler, but its quite a good sentence and gets the spirit.

Answer (score 5):

It's similar to [Bart Simpson's "Eat my shorts"](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Eat_My_Shorts!).
Obviously it's a colloquial phrase created by some designer who committed to the ongoing "unicorn" trend.
A unicorn stands for freedom, self-fulfillment, emancipation, never giving a damn on what others demand or expect one to do.
The unicorn proceeds making its own way, dispersing a cloud of "stardust" on its way to universe. All the "Langweiler" (slowpokes) can do is inhaling/eating (pejorative: "fressen") the dust while staying in their daily grind.

Comment: Ha! Unicorn farts :-D ...

Comment: :-D indeed. :-)

Comment: Should we put an [illustration](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c9/cd/52/c9cd5232feee65a5e8c6d7cf699827b5--majestic-unicorn-unicorn-farts.jpg)? ;-) ...

Answer (score 2):

Unless somebody added this in the last 10 hours this is what my Google translate spits out:

[image]

> Devour my stardust, you slowpoke!

Apart from the missing plural in *Langweiler* there is nothing wrong with this translation. It has the same weird meaning in German.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell, but the meaning is the same as saying: "Well folks, I will leave you and you have nothing left but the dust."

So to say, the thinker or writer of the phrase meant: Patience is over :-)

Sternenstaub, everything is made out of this, so is your Endocannabinoid System.